# Using font-awesome in thunderbird signature

Tags: font-awesome, thunderbird

Is it possible to use font-awesome in Thunderbird signatures?

So far, I've tried embedding the code from [fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started) in the HTML signature, as follows:

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> (Street Address here) <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> etc...
```

but this isn't working. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong, or can it not be done?

Comment: I tried embedding the code from http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/ in HTML signature, as follows:

<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> (Street Address here)
<i class="fa fa-phone"></i> (phone number here)

etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that, like a lot of CSS techniques, it won't work in emails. Blame Microsoft for insisting that Outlook uses Word as its rendering engine.

CSS support in email is a tangled nightmare. Campaign Monitor do a very useful guide to it [here](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

Comment: Thank you. And thanks for editing my original question - looks much better.
So I guess I'll continue to use embedded images in my signatures...

Comment: No problem. Embedded images and tables are sadly still the only way to design emails...